# After making changes in one TFS branch, how do I update other branches?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

i have a branch in TFS from my main team project. The changes that have been done on the branch, I want those files to be updated in my main Team project. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

From a Visual Studio 2008 command line, you can use the [tf merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(VS.80).aspx) command. From the Source Control explorer, you can use the [Merge Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364074(VS.80).aspx#vs05teamsys_topic8).